# Validate elements outside a form

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have some elements (input, textarea, controlgroup) and a submit button outside of a form element...

Can I validate those elements (client-side)? For instance, check if they are required and show a message error if they are empty. Can I use jquery validation plugin to do that? How?

Here is a sample of my code until now:

```
<div id="formContainer">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>User:</legend>
            <div id="usersContainer">
               <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="1" />
               <label for="radio-choice-1">User1</label>
               <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="2" />
               <label for="radio-choice-2">User2</label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <label for="subjectMessage">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" name="subjectMessage" id="subjectMessage" value="" placeholder="Subject" />
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <label for="bodyMessage">Body:</label>
        <textarea name="bodyMessage" id="bodyMessage" placeholder="Body" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input id="sendMessageBtn" type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).one("pageinit", function () {

        $("#sendMessageBtn").on("click", function () {

            var userId= $('#formContainer').find("#usersContainer :radio:checked").val();
            var subject = $('#formContainer').find("#subjectMessage").val();
            var body = $('#formContainer').find("#bodyMessage").val();

            //send data to the server...
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: To use the jQuery Validate plugin, your input elements **must** be contained inside a form element.

Comment: @Sparky My problem with the form element is because those data should be sent to a different server (cross domain) and I was not able to send the data, it always sent to the action in the controller. I was using `Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions {
    Url = "Cross domain URL",
    HttpMethod="Get"
})`. Was I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 approaches.

1. You don't use server side helpers to generate the markup and have hardcoded your entire markup (as shown in your question). This is very bad but if you decide to go with that approach you will have to add the corresponding `data-*` attributes to your input fields that the unobtrusive validation framework is using. It's perfectly possible to use the unobtrusive validation framework outside ASP.NET MVC, for example in a PHP application assuming your input fields contain those data-* attributes. But as I said in my previous sentece: `outside an ASp.NET MVC application` which begs the question: `Why are you using ASP.NET MVC in this case if you do not take advantage of it?`. So I would recommend you scraping this approach and look at the second possibility.
2. You use server side helpers to generate those input fields such as Html.EditorFor, Html.TextAreaFor, Html.DropDownListFor, ... Those helpers will take care of generating the proper `data-*` attributes under one condition: those elements are inside a form. This is not your case, so you could cheat by adding the following line to the top of your view to trick them into thinking that they are inside a form:

   ```
   @{
       this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm a bit confused because I'm not using models into my view... But I could use something like: `@Html.Label(...)` am I right? Another issue that I'm having is because the controlgroup is rendered before, at client-side... If I use server-side helpers, where should I define which elements are required, which are the messages error and where they are shown? Can you help me with this?